# php://input found on url

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

I am running my website under IIS with asp.net as my language.

errors encountered in my site are sent to me via email when I found something containing `php://input` like `MySite/Page?id=php://input`

my questions are, what does `php://input` do? can php queries be executed on IIS Servers?

Thanks for your answers and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks most likely like an automated hacking attempt looking for injection vulnerabilities of a PHP application. Nothing you need to be concerned of with ASP.net. Basically PHP allows some URLs in file names. So the idea of the hack is to use one of those URLs to see if the input strings are used unvalidated.

Comment: thanks a lot!, I can breath a lot better now. I was kind of puzzled on what to do about this issue.